# Getting error when I attach an image to Classpath Resource in scheduler jobclass

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

```
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException 
{
  System.out.println("Sending Birthday Wishes... ");

   try
   {
            for(int i=0;i<maillist.length;i++)
            {   


            Email email = new Email();
            email.setFrom("spv_it@yahoo.com");
            email.setSubject("Happy IndependenceDay");
            email.setTo(maillist[i]);

            email.setText("<font color=blue><h4>Dear Users,<br><br><br>Wish you a Happy Independence Day!<br><br><br>Regards,<br>Penna Cement Industries Limited</h4></font>");
            byte[] data = null;
            ClassPathResource img = new ClassPathResource("newLogo.gif");
            InputStream inputStream = img.getInputStream();
            data = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            while((inputStream.read(data)!=-1));

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(data, "HappyBirthDay","image/gif", true);
            email.addAttachment(attachment);

            emailService.sendEmail(email);
        }


   }
   catch (MessagingException e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

 }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [newLogo.gif] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:135)
at com.mail.schedular.BirthdayWisherJob.executeInternal(BirthdayWisherJob.java:55)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:66)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

Comment: Help with what? What have you tried, what is your expectation?

One hint: is there a "newLogo.gif" on your classpath?

Another hint: your logic for reading the resource will only work if you are very lucky. Google how to read files / resources from a InputStream.

A third hint: Is it really necessary to read that gif for every recipient freshly from disk? That byte[] does not go bad from one loop to the next.

Comment: We **at least** need to know what a ClassPathResource is

Comment: @tieTYT this you can already know by the stacktrace and question tag: org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource

Answer (score 0):

The best practise is to read/write or to provide reference of any file is **by mentioning the ABSOLUTE PATH of that file**.
To your question, It shows the **FileNotFoundException** because, JVM failed to locate the file in your current directory which is by default your source path. So provide the absolute path in **ClassPathResource** or copy that image file to your current directory. It will solve your problem.

Comment: This is actually not very good advice as this ties your program to an absolute file path.
Either make that path configurable if you need to change it, or package it with your program (in the jar/war/... you provide) if the resource does not change.
The latter option was chosen by user2396478 by loading the resource from the application's classpath.

Comment: thanks for reply. i am sending birthday wishes to list of employee by using quartz scheduler. the scheduler is running successfully but when iam attaching image then i showing error..

Comment: It's not actually looking in the "current directory" - it's a `ClassPathResource` so it's looking in the root of the classpath. Make sure that's where the file is, or use a `FileSystemResource` instead.

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion.it is working with FileSystemResource

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your file inside inside the src folder , if it's there then check whether it's under some directory which is inside the src directory.

Then give the correct location like given details below
src[dir]----->newLogo.gif

```
ClassPathResource img = new ClassPathResource("newLogo.gif");
```

or,
src[dir]----->images[dir]---->newLogo.gif

```
ClassPathResource img = new ClassPathResource("/images/newLogo.gif");
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this error since the job is running in a separate quartz thread, I suggest that you locate your file *newLogo.gif* outside the jar and use the following to load it.
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("classpath:image/newLogo.gif");`